# PubSub-js cannot access functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, typeerror, publish-subscribe

I am fairly new to using PubSubJS (along with jQuery, Webpack, React) in a project, and my local server throws the following error

> Uncaught TypeError: _pubsubJs2.default.subscribe is not a function
>    at Object.componentDidMount (SideNavContainer.js?eb9e:44)
>   ...

this line

```
import PubSub from 'pubsub-js';
...
PubSub.subscribe(OPEN_LAYERS, (_, isOpen) => {
  this.setState({ active: isOpen });
  this.props.isOpen(isOpen);
});
```

I've successfully run PubSubJS in a blank test project, and so maybe there's an issue with how Webpack is building? My webpack.config.js file compiles using babel. I'll include more source code if need be!

Comment: Can you import and run other packages?  Is React working?  You should probably add more of your component or the webpack config.  Can't tell what's wrong from what you've got here.

Comment: thanks @jmargolisvt. I believe other packages are imported and run properly. React is working. Commenting out this PubSub line will error out at another PubSub line. I'm also getting a jQuery.Deffered exception warning for the same error. I didn't want to dump my config, but here's a [link](https://gist.github.com/thomas-hervey/11dfb076fc347d6b10ca60d00f294f34) to the two files.

Comment: Just to be sure... and you've got pubsub in your package.json and you've run `npm i`?  Assuming that's all true, do you see pubsub in your package-lock.json?

Comment: Yes, it's present in both. I've added package.json and a screenshot to the gist ^. I've tried deleted .node_modules, dist/, and rerunning the build.

Comment: could you solve your problem? i am having the same issue